# TypeError: href is undefined when customer login

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento 2.3.3

> Problem when customer login, all pages response with error TypeError:
>   href is undefined

code that related to this error

```
<?php
$controllerName1 = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName1 = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
$routeName1 = $this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$moduleName1 = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
?>
<?php if(!($routeName1 == "checkout" && $controllerName1 == "index" && $actionName1 == "index")): ?>
    <div class="block block-customer-login block-header-customer-login">
        <div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
            <form class="form form-login"
                    action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>"
                    method="post"
                    id="header-login-form"
                    data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
                    <div class="field email required">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getUsername()) ?>" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) :?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> id="email" type="email" class="input-text" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field password required">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="login[password]" type="password" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) :?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text" id="pass" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions-toolbar">
                        <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign In') ?></span></button></div>
                        <div class="secondary"><a class="action remind" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Forgot Your Password?') ?></span></a></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery'
        ], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var href = $(".header.links .authorization-link > a").attr("href");
                if(href.indexOf("logout") == -1) {
                    $(".block-header-customer-login").detach().appendTo(".authorization-link");
                    $(".block-header-customer-login").click(function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    })
                    $("html,body").click(function(){
                        if($(".block-header-customer-login").hasClass("open"))
                            $(".block-header-customer-login").removeClass("open");
                    });
                    $(".header.links .authorization-link > a").off("click").on("click", function(){
                        if(!$(".block-header-customer-login").hasClass("open"))
                            $(".block-header-customer-login").addClass("open");
                        else
                            $(".block-header-customer-login").removeClass("open");

                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

any have can share how to fix this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your JavaScript code with this one..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var href = $(".header.links .authorization-link > a").attr("href");
            if(typeof href !== typeof undefined && href !== false && href.indexOf("logout") == -1) {
                $(".block-header-customer-login").detach().appendTo(".authorization-link");
                $(".block-header-customer-login").click(function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                })
                $("html,body").click(function(){
                    if($(".block-header-customer-login").hasClass("open"))
                        $(".block-header-customer-login").removeClass("open");
                });
                $(".header.links .authorization-link > a").off("click").on("click", function(){
                    if(!$(".block-header-customer-login").hasClass("open"))
                        $(".block-header-customer-login").addClass("open");
                    else
                        $(".block-header-customer-login").removeClass("open");

                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Approve my answer if this will help you! Thanks :)

Comment: Yes this fixed my problem, thank you so much

Comment: If it was helpful to you then you can accept my answer and give an upvote for me. Thanks :)

Comment: still cant upvote, but really appreciate your answer

Comment: @Yustian Thanks Buddy. Happy to help you! 